# Do I need to use the same passport when entering Japan?

Tags: passports

I have two passports, one Hong Kong and one US. I have always used the Hong Kong one to enter Japan, but it is about to expire. Can I use my US passport to enter Japan this time, or do I always have to use the same one?

Comment: There is no such rule. You can use whichever is a valid document that allows you entry into the country.

Answer (score 2):

I have two passports and go to Japan a few times a year. I use whichever one I have on hand (as I travel a lot, I rotate between both) and was never asked about the other.

There are countries that insist on using the same passport (Malaysia comes to mind), but Japan isn't one of them.

Comment: The hell? You're saying if ever having used a Hong Kong passport for Malaysia, the same person won't be allowed to use anything else again? What if they renounce their Chinese nationality, for example?

Comment: I never said Malaysian immigration was being reasonable ☺ It happens to me quite regularly. I think they hate it that I rotate between passports. They keep insisting that I use the passport I used before. I just say "sorry, cannot" and ignore them. But you never know when shit will hit the fan, especially in Malaysia.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't expect that in one of the most lax countries I've been to

Comment: @coke Malaysia is deceptively lax-looking. It isn't quite that lax, actually, and the Bumiputera civil servants can be actually extremely rigid actually.

Comment: I just came home from being a guest at a Singaporean university (through my own uni in Switzerland) for 45 days, whilst having my hotel in Malaysian Johor Bahru. The Singaporeans got half-suspicious a few times and wanted to see my hotel reservation and the invitation from the uni explaining exactly what I was doing there. The Malaysians, though, couldn't possibly have cared less. Scan and stamp with no questions asked, that's what happened (I'm on a Swedish passport FWIW)